# How to lookup based on N/A

Tags: r

I have a main table with 10K like this, some rows with missing N/A fields across different columns.

| Name | Brand | Country | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Samsung | N/A | Blue |
| Mary | N/A | USA | N/A |
| Sarah | Nokia | USA | Green |

I have another brand table like this.

| Name | Brand |
| --- | --- |
| Mary | Nokia |

(And another table for color and another table for country)

I want to say that if Mary has a N/A in blank, then to lookup her value in the brand table. If she has a blank in Color, then lookup her value in the color table. Same for George and the N/A for his country. For the purposes of this exercise, I don't want to override any existing fields (e.g., I want to keep Samsung and Blue for George, not replace them).

Tried a left_join but not sure how to do a if statement in conjunction

Comment: Please provide reproducible data and code that you have tried. It looks like the `N/A` in your data are likely characters and not the `NA` value as dealt with by R. If that's the case the solution will differ, but without the actual data there's no way to know!

Comment: If you have actual `NA` (and not `"N/A"`) values you can do `library(dplyr); main_table %>% rows_patch(brand_table, by = "Name") %>% rows_patch(color_table, by = "Name") %>% rows_patch(country_table, by = "Name")`. If you don't have actual `NA` values then your first step should be to replace your `"N/A"`s with `NA`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Let's build test data first.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

tb_origin <- 
  tb_base %>% 
  mutate(
    vs = na_if(vs, 0),
    am = na_if(am, 1),
    gear = na_if(gear, 3)
  )
tb_new <- tb_base %>% select(car, vs, am, gear)
```

`tb_origin` looks like this:

```
tb_origin
```

```
> tb_origin
# A tibble: 32 × 4
   car                  vs    am  gear
   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Mazda RX4            NA    NA     4
 2 Mazda RX4 Wag        NA    NA     4
 3 Datsun 710            1    NA     4
 4 Hornet 4 Drive        1     0    NA
 5 Hornet Sportabout    NA     0    NA
 6 Valiant               1     0    NA
 7 Duster 360           NA     0    NA
 8 Merc 240D             1     0     4
 9 Merc 230              1     0     4
10 Merc 280              1     0     4
# ℹ 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

You are right about comparing data by using `left_join()`, here is how to use it:

```
left_join(tb_origin, tb_new, by = "car", suffix = c(".x" = "", ".y" = "_new"))
```

```
# A tibble: 32 × 7
   car                  vs    am  gear vs_new am_new gear_new
   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Mazda RX4            NA    NA     4      0      1        4
 2 Mazda RX4 Wag        NA    NA     4      0      1        4
 3 Datsun 710            1    NA     4      1      1        4
 4 Hornet 4 Drive        1     0    NA      1      0        3
 5 Hornet Sportabout    NA     0    NA      0      0        3
 6 Valiant               1     0    NA      1      0        3
 7 Duster 360           NA     0    NA      0      0        3
 8 Merc 240D             1     0     4      1      0        4
 9 Merc 230              1     0     4      1      0        4
10 Merc 280              1     0     4      1      0        4
# ℹ 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

And here is how to replace `NA` with your rules:

```
tb_result <- 
  tb_origin %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = c(vs, am, gear),
      .fns = ~ if_else(!is.na(.x), .x, tb_new[[cur_column()]])
    )
  )
tb_result
```

```
> tb_result
# A tibble: 32 × 4
   car                  vs    am  gear
   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Mazda RX4             0     1     4
 2 Mazda RX4 Wag         0     1     4
 3 Datsun 710            1     1     4
 4 Hornet 4 Drive        1     0     3
 5 Hornet Sportabout     0     0     3
 6 Valiant               1     0     3
 7 Duster 360            0     0     3
 8 Merc 240D             1     0     4
 9 Merc 230              1     0     4
10 Merc 280              1     0     4
# ℹ 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Here is the final compareson:

```
> left_join(tb_origin, tb_new, by = "car", suffix = c(".x" = "", ".y" = "_new")) %>% 
+   left_join(tb_result, by = "car", suffix = c(".x" = "", ".y" = "_after_replace"))
# A tibble: 32 × 10
   car           vs    am  gear vs_new am_new gear_new vs_after_replace am_after_replace gear_after_replace
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 Mazda RX4     NA    NA     4      0      1        4                0                1                  4
 2 Mazda RX4…    NA    NA     4      0      1        4                0                1                  4
 3 Datsun 710     1    NA     4      1      1        4                1                1                  4
 4 Hornet 4 …     1     0    NA      1      0        3                1                0                  3
 5 Hornet Sp…    NA     0    NA      0      0        3                0                0                  3
 6 Valiant        1     0    NA      1      0        3                1                0                  3
 7 Duster 360    NA     0    NA      0      0        3                0                0                  3
 8 Merc 240D      1     0     4      1      0        4                1                0                  4
 9 Merc 230       1     0     4      1      0        4                1                0                  4
10 Merc 280       1     0     4      1      0        4                1                0                  4
# ℹ 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```